# PhoneGap Build Failing for iOS though It Works for Android Fine

Tags: phonegap

I tried to run the Adobe PhoneGap build for a hybrid App. It worked fine for Android but failed for iOS though everything was working OK earlier. I have updated the phonegap-version as the following:

```
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-8.0.0' />
```

The error log shows the following:

```
copy  splash.png ../../../../private/project/www/splash.png (new file)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
    at parseWhitelistUrlForATS (/private/project/cordova/lib/prepare.js:1038:26)
    at /private/project/cordova/lib/prepare.js:965:23
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at processAccessAndAllowNavigationEntries (/private/project/cordova/lib/prepare.js:956:10)
    at writeATSEntries (/private/project/cordova/lib/prepare.js:1081:16)
    at updateProject (/private/project/cordova/lib/prepare.js:217:15)
    at /private/project/cordova/lib/prepare.js:59:20
    at _fulfilled (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
```

---

before ending. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the CLI version to cli-6.5.0

```
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-6.5.0' />
```

and it worked. It looks higher version creates issues.